# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeDatabaseError: Unknown column 'model.coulmn_name' in 'where clause'

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

i use Sequelize

what i want search userId from another model

when i add **"task_customer_order.userId"** i got error but when i remove it only **userId** it's work but foreign key of **userId** in **Comment** model not need it i want in **task_customer_order** model

my code :

```
 count_comment:async(req,res)=>{
          var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
          const id = req.params.id;
        
          await   Comment.findAll({
            attributes: { 
              include: [[Sequelize.fn("COUNT", Sequelize.col('comment.publish')), "count_Comment"]],
            },
            include: ['task_customer_order'],
            where:[{"publish":1,"task_customer_order.userId":{[Op.like]:id}}],
            }).then(data => {
            res.send(data)
          })
        
        },
```

error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeDatabaseError: Unknown column 'comment.task_customer_order.userId' in 'where clause'
```

output without userId:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "title_body": "1",
    "publish": true,
    "createdAt": "2021-01-04T17:34:46.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2021-01-04T17:57:52.000Z",
    "taskCustomerOrderId": 1,
    "userId": 2,     <============= i don't need it 
    "count_Comment": 6,
    "task_customer_order": {
        "id": 1,
        "title_task": "yy",
        "description": "",
        "endAt": "2021-02-12T21:00:00.000Z",
        "duration": "09-02",
        "publish": true,
        "createdAt": "2021-01-04T17:32:47.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-01-04T21:49:15.000Z",
        "customerOrderId": 1,
        "userId": 1   <==================== i want this 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to filter by userId in joined task_customer_order - you need to put condition inside include. Try the next:

```
await   Comment.findAll({
        attributes: { 
          include: [[Sequelize.fn("COUNT", Sequelize.col('comment.publish')), "count_Comment"]],
        },
        include: [{ model: TaskCustomerOrder, where:{userId: {[Op.like]:id}}}],
        where:{"publish”:1},
        }).then(data => {
        res.send(data)
      })
```

Comment: your code very great but must add as after model and it's work thank you so much for help

Answer (score 0):

here Code After solving :

```
   count_comment:async(req,res)=>{
          var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
          const id = req.params.id;
        
          await   Comment.findAll({
            attributes: { 
              include: [[Sequelize.fn("COUNT", Sequelize.col('comment.publish')), "count_Comment"]],


            },
         
            include: [{ model: TaskCustomerOrder,as:'task_customer_order', where:{'userId': {[Op.like]:id}}}],
            where:{publish:1},
           
          
            }).then(data => {
            res.send(data)
          })
        
        },
```